# There seems to be an error in the Codility evaluation

Tags: reactjs, innerhtml, innertext

This is an example of marking the time result value in the H1 tag (count down and mark the given time)

```
// Codility not aware of this setting
document.getElementById("h1TagId").innerText = "00:05";
```

```
// But Codility to be able to evaluate these settings
document.getElementById("h1TagId").innerText = "00:05";
```

Isn't there a problem with this evaluation?

Answer (score 0):

you can not use document.get functions in React, as React is using virtual DOM instead of traditional DOM, instead, you have to use useRef hook, I cant see your code, but this is how you should use it(first, you have to import useRef from react):

```
const inputEl = useRef(null);

const onButtonClick = () => {
    
    inputEl.current.innerText = "00:05";
  };
```

and on return function:

```
 return (
    <>
      <p ref={inputEl}> </p>
      <button onClick={onButtonClick}>change the innertext!</button>
    </>
  );
```

see docs on useRef here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref